# Meteor npm install produces error: EIO i/o error

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, meteor, cmd

Trying to work with meteor on bash on ubunutu on windows and after installing node and meteor I run on my dir root:

`meteor npm install`

And I get:

meteor npm install

```
/home/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.13j49n2++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/dev-bundle.js:113
      throw e;
      ^

Error: EIO: i/o error, stat '/mnt/d/app/.meteor/local/dev_bundle'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:844:18)
    at statOrNull (/home/mateo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.13j49n2++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/dev-bundle.js:110:19)
    at getDevBundleDir (/home/mateo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.13j49n2++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/dev-bundle.js:31:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mateo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.13j49n2++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/dev-bundle.js:172:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

So I go to .meteor/local/dev_bundle and see this:

[image]

HAve no idea what to do with this strange error. I'm using "bash on ubunutu on windows" which is Bash on Windows 10.